# Python 2.7.12, trying to build an executable file using pyinstaller. I keep getting the below error

Tags: python-2.7, flask, pyinstaller

Trying to build an executable file using pyinstaller. I keep getting the below error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Inventory_Computation\app.py", line 145, in <module>
      File "flask\app.py", line 843, in run
      File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 692, in run_simple
      File "werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 248, in run_with_reloader
      File "werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 129, in run
      File "werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 22, in _iter_module_files
      File "Lib\email\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    ImportError: No module named message
    Failed to execute script app
```

Comment: Use the [`--hidden-import`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) option for the message module.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution finally...

1. Go to "C:\Python27\Lib\email"
2. And find the "**init**.py"
3. Comment out below lines.

   'Audio',
   'Base',
   'Image',
   'Message',
   'Multipart',
   'NonMultipart',
   'Text',

Try pyinstaller again